# Disable/off Expires headers htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

earlier i tried to expires headers. but my site always update. then i put my expires headers to htaccess file. so now not get quick update from web browser. so its very dangerous for my site. now i want to disable it. how to do it and if someone know help for fix it to my site. my site is tv episode sites. so always update and css also update. here my .htaccess code

> firstly give me to disable code
>
> secoundly give me to fix this code to like our web site (tv episode site. from seconds upload any programs to our site)

/.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>

# Enable expirations
ExpiresActive On

# Default directive
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"

# My favicon
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year”

# Images
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"

# CSS
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month”

# Javascript
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 year"

</IfModule>
```

Comment: how did you resolve this issue? I have the same issue

Answer (score 0):

I was also looking for solving such a problem.
Even tried setting **ExpiresActive Off** - but that didn't help.

the only solution that worked was setting the date to 1 minute:

```
# CSS
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 minutes"
```

Comment: Maybe this will be more appropriate:

    # CSS
    ExpiresByType text/css A0